# How to efficiently remove all series from highchart/highstock and then add many more

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have to dynamically first remove all the series and then add many more series to both Highchart and Highstock. I am using the following way to achieve this:

```
while (highcharts.series[0]) {
    highcharts.series[0].remove(true);
}

allSeries = []; //it has all the new series to be added

allSeries.forEach(function (series) {
    highcharts.addSeries(series);
});
```

But this is a very heavy operation and takes a lot of time. Is there any way to achieving this in a cost-effective way such that it takes less time.

Comment: how many series do you have normally it should not take that much time although it takes approx4 secs to remove around 100 series see this [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/buttflattery/srZU2/140/)

Answer (score 2):

It's going to take a lot of time if you perform redraw on each series remove operation (first argument of `Series.remove()` is responsible for controlling this).

It's much faster if you redraw the chart only once - after all the removals are completed:

```
for(var i = chart.series.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    chart.series[i].remove(false);
}
chart.redraw();
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/szd1dc81/

Same approach can be used while adding the series.